# Change y-axis center in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, continuous

Is there anyway to move the "center" of the y-axis to 1 in ggplot instead of 0? I have ratio data so I'm trying to visualize it in a way where the the values are above or below 1, not above or below 0. So far I just subtracted 1 from the data and have it centered around 0 - but I've been unsuccessful on relabeling the y-axis so that it reflects the numbers I want.

```
chi_ratios_plot  <-  ggplot(data=chi_ratios, aes(x = metric, y =ratio2, fill=coral_cover))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  theme_classic()+
  coord_flip()
```

there's my code. Here's what I have so far:
[image]
the 0 should really be a 1, the -1 should really be a 0, etc.

Comment: *"I'm trying to visualize it in a way where the the values are above or below 1, not above or below 0"* It's quite common to log-transform ratios, which will give you the scale you're after: Log ratios < 0 correspond to ratios < 1, and > 0 correspond to ratios > 1.

Comment: ya, I've done that before, but I was trying to recreate a figure someone made in excel that they had it centered at 1, but I think I might just have to argue for the log-transform

Comment: From a statistics point of view, log-transforming a ratio is often a sensible choice, as ratio data are often (at least approximately) log-normally distributed. I have never seen ratio data being linearly shifted to be centred at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using your manually shifted ratio values, you can fix up their labels by providing a `labels` argument to `scale_y_continuous` and shifting them back up to 1:

```
chi_ratios = expand.grid(
    metric = c("A", "B", "C"),
    coral_cover = c("Low", "Med", "High")
) %>%
    # ratio: actual ratios
    # ratio2: shifted so they're centered at 0
    mutate(ratio = rnorm(n(), mean = 1, sd = 2),
           ratio2 = ratio - 1)


ggplot(data=chi_ratios, aes(x = metric, y = ratio2, fill = coral_cover)) +
    geom_col(position="dodge") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(breaks) { breaks + 1}) +
    theme_classic() +
    coord_flip()
```

I can't see any option to override the 0 baseline in either `geom_bar()` or `geom_col()`, and achieving the same thing with `geom_rect()` would be fiddly, so this seems like the easiest option.